# How to form multiply column from a single pandas.apply() call ?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which returns a tuple of 4 items.

I have a DataFrame, what I want is to add 4 new column to my DataFrame by applying a function on one of the column. How to do it?

Below is my attempt:

```
a['w'], a['x'], a['y'], a['z'] =
a["existing"].apply(lambda x: find_data_from_ip(x))
```

But as this is a test DataFrame with only two row, I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need return `Series` from function:

```
def find_data_from_ip(x):
    tup = (1,2,3,4)
    return (pd.Series(tup, index=['w','x','y','z']))

a = pd.DataFrame({'existing':[1,2,3]})
print (a)

a[['w','x','y','z']] = a["existing"].apply(lambda x: find_data_from_ip(x))
print (a)
   existing  w  x  y  z
0         1  1  2  3  4
1         2  1  2  3  4
2         3  1  2  3  4
```

Another solution is create `DataFrame` from column of tuples by [`from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to original:

```
def find_data_from_ip(x):
    tup = (1,2,3,4)
    return (tup)

a = pd.DataFrame({'existing':[1,2,3]})
#print (a)

print (a["existing"].apply(lambda x: find_data_from_ip(x)))
0    (1, 2, 3, 4)
1    (1, 2, 3, 4)
2    (1, 2, 3, 4)
Name: existing, dtype: object

a1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(a["existing"].apply(lambda x: find_data_from_ip(x))
                                            .values
                                            .tolist(),
                               columns = ['w','x','y','z'])
print (a1)
   w  x  y  z
0  1  2  3  4
1  1  2  3  4
2  1  2  3  4

print (pd.concat([a,a1],axis=1))
   existing  w  x  y  z
0         1  1  2  3  4
1         2  1  2  3  4
2         3  1  2  3  4
```